# Cant read the controller

Tags: angularjs

I've just learned AngularJs. I've try to show a data from controller. but the data not show.
my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Belajar AngularJs</title>
</head>
    <body ng-app="FirstApp">
        <div ng-controller="MainController">
            {{title}} </br>
            {{book.title}} </br>
            {{book.author}} </br>
            {{book.price}} 
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/MainController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my controller :

```
app controller('MainController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // body...
    $scope.title='Belajar AngularJs';
    $scope.book={
        title: 'Belajar Angularjs Bersama Ciwuk',
        author : 'Ciwuk';
        price : 'Free'
    };
}]);
```

my model :

```
var app=angular.module('FirstApp',[]);
```

the result was like this :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5W8v.png)

anyone help me please? i'm new in angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `app.controller` and `author : 'Ciwuk',`. Use comma not semicolon.
Try use console(F12) when error happen.

Answer (score 0):

@DieuNQ pointed correct to your typo. But here is even better way:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('your_module_name', []).controller("MainController", [
```